# Programmatically click link in Joomla

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I have this link:

```
<a id="launch_crop" class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_registration&view=crop&tmpl=component" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 680, y: 370}}">Show modal2</a>
```

that opens a lightbox; i would like to click it programmatically at the end of an operaration.

If i do 
    jQuery("#launch_crop").trigger("click"); or
    jQuery("#launch_crop").click();

it does not work and does not give errors in console. How can i force the click on a link?

Comment: I guess you have to bind the click event to the element prior to trigger it